# How can i play video (By Name) from document directory ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video

In my application i store my video in document directory with name is `'video2.MOV'` and i want to play it.

Here problem is that i am not able to get this video *(name is `'video2.MOV'`)* from document directory.

**My Code :**

```
-(void)playVideo:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video2.MOV"];
    NSLog(@"filePath - %@",filePath);

    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"contentPath - %@",content);

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:content]];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
}
```

In console, each time i got **`contentPath`** is `NULL`, so may be i am not able to play video.

Here, What is my mistake. please give me suggestion on this issue.

Comment: is ur filepath correct ?

Comment: @IronManGill- yes it is correct ..

Comment: `NSArray * content = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: filePath];` and in CDDirector your url objectAtIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (NSString*)GetDocumentFilePath:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSLog(@"%@",filename);
    // NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString* file = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",filename];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
    {
        //NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"plist"]; //5

        //[fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error]; //6
    }  

    return path;
}
```

and get file path like this:

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self GetDoucmentPath:path]];


MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:pptURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(60, 20, 700, 500);
    theMovie.view.center = self.view.center;

    //[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];

    // Register for the playback finished notification. 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(onStop) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:theMovie];

    // Movie playback is asynchronous, so this method returns immediately. 

    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    [theMovie play];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Thanks you answer is help full for me,, i need only `NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:MyFullPath]];`

Comment: You are always welcome dear... its whole code beacause it may help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `content` use `filePath` instead to get to the movie file:

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
```

Comment: you answer is correct but you need to write `fileURLWithPath` instead of `URLWithString `.. :)

Comment: Oh Yeah you are right. Editing so that others wont be confused.